# putty + powerlevel10k - font issue

Tags: ssh, terminal, fonts, putty, zsh

I'm running ubuntu with zsh and powerlevel10k and that works just fine on the graphical terminal. I don't really use the TTY terminals, and if I do I can manage to make sense of the broken fonts, so that's not an issue.
However when I connect with putty I get a lot of broken symbology on the terminal.
I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.mordsgau.de/oh-my-zsh-with-putty/) to fix it but it didn't work. Previously I had installed the same font (the one recommended on the powerlevel10k github page) I installed on ubuntu on the windows machine and set that as the font, that didn't work either. Then I tried following this tutorial, uninstalled the old font (`MesloLGS NF Regular`) and instead installed the recommended fonts (all four of `Meslo LG L DZ Regular|Italic|Bold|Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf`) and set them as the font to be used in putty. I get the same broken display.

The broken display looks something like this (hostname, username redacted. They show up okay for me):

[image: Broken fonts in putty]

instead of like this (made using xforwarding and opening the graphical terminal):

[image: Non broken fonts in mate-terminal]

Just using xforwarding and opening `mate-terminal` all the time is not desirable because of the lag and extra network usage. And it's a really ugly solution anyway.

Comment: Might be better off on server fault, please migrate

Answer (score 1):

1. Set UTF-8 encoding in KiTTY/PuTTY settings Windows-> Translation.
2. Use patched Nerd Fonts, eg Fura/Fira Mono Powerline: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/FiraMono

Comment: That didn't fix it either. It just looks differently broken now. I installed the `Fira Mono Windows compatible` font.